How to clean up CA1000 corrosion inhibitive compound?
I am working on one of the aircraft parts covered in CA1000 corrosion inhibiting compound that needs to be cleaned and reapplied. I looked at their website and it says it is "a one-part, epoxy capped, PERMAPOL® polysulfide compound".
I have tried using parts cleaner (kerosene-based) and workshop solvent (Naphtha) to clean it with no success. Just wondering if anyone knows how to clean it.

Why not contact the manufacturer and ask them?

Mastinox is formulated to be resistant to fuels, so you wouldn't expect Naptha or kerosene to work in the first place.
Suggest you try denatured alchohol, isopropyl alcohol, or acetone.

This product sounds very similar similar to PRC Pro-Seal, which is also a polysulfide sealant that never becomes fully solid and is very resistant to pretty much any solvent or fuel. If this is the case, you should try heating it with a hot air dryer such as is used to shrink shrink-tube material. Heating it should soften it enough to allow it to be scraped off with a spatula.
